# Table view index not displayed for contacts in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am not able to view the section index titles in the index area of the table view. I have used the same code but its working in ios 6.0 but not working in ios 7.

I have tried the following:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (isContacts) // contacts button is pressed
    {
        return indexArray; // return the section titles as indexes.
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work here ?

Comment: The index is displayed when i run this code in 6.0 simulator and not displayed when i run it in 7.0 simulator. :-(

Comment: There is nothing specific in the part of code you gave us. Probably it's problem somewhere else. Does it maybe show any errors / warnings in xcode ? Maybe you are using some deprecated methods.

Comment: I have checked by putting a break point here and the first condition (is contacts) is yes and the control is entering into the loop and the index array has 7 objects to display as index..i have printed them in the console but they are not displayed on the simulator 7.0. To summarise my table index is not shown in 7.0 and shown in 6.0 simulators.

Answer (score 0):

@Raj I know this response is coming late but it might help others. The issue could be the size of your view. I had the same problem which had me scratching my head only to realize it was a width problem with my view. Reducing the size of the view during testing showed me my index.

Hope this helps someone!